Add loop list in python selenium find by xpath
keylist = ['1468384','1374165','1335571','1322769']
for item in keylist:
driver.get(f"mylinkshow_by_id=" +item) working 1 by 1

Firstname= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("//input[@name='FirstName"+item+""))
value1 = Firsname.get_dom_attribute("value")
    


getting error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
its working like this //input[@name='FirstName1468384'] but when I try to loop it from key list its not working.

Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Are you sure this is your real code?  It has two different variables named Firstname and Firsname.  Surely that is an error?

And please fix the indentation to reflect the actual code.  Right now, there could be problems caused indentation.
